# Two ListPicker, one TextBox. Result not displayed. Master-Detail?

Tags: c#, if-statement, windows-phone-8, master-detail, listpicker

I have two ListPickers originating from one TextBox.

```
    private void textBox3_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string a = "Domestic";
        string b = Convert.ToString(textBox2.Text);
        string c = "Foreign";

        if (b == a)
        {
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/ListPickerExchanges1.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }
        else if (b == c)
            {
                NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/ListPickerExchanges2.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
            }
```

Both ListPickers load and give you the option to choose something from the list. But **only one ListPicker will displays the selection back** into TextBox3 , and **it is always the one under the second Else If (b == c) condition.**

The ListPickerExchanges1 under the first condition will not display the selection back into textbox3.

**But** if i change the code under the second Else If condition to navigate to Exchanges1 instead of Exchanges2, then the Exchanges1 listpicker displays back the selection into textbox 3, and Exchanges2 does not.

Which means, **Everything under the second condition works, and does not under the first condition**.

Here is the code behind ListpickerExchanges1, which is intended to display the selection back into the textbox.

```
          public partial class ListPickerExchanges1 : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public ListPickerExchanges1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(ListPickerExchanges1_Loaded);
    }
    private void ListPickerExchanges1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgse)
    {
        ListBoxExchanges.ItemsSource = Page2.ListExchanges;
    }
      public void Selection(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        ListBox myselecteditem4 = (ListBox)sender;
        ItemsModeling4 item4 = (ItemsModeling4)myselecteditem4.SelectedItem;            
        if (item4 != null)
        {
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Broker.xaml?name4=" + item4.Exchanges, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
        }
         }
```

..............................................................................................................................................................
Update: Additional Code behind Navigation and Selection

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        string name4 = "";
        NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("name4", out name4);
        textBox3.Text = string.Format("{0}", name4);
    }
```

..............................................................................................................................................................

```
    public Page2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ListExchanges = new ObservableCollection<ItemsModeling4>();
        this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(Page44_Loaded);
    }
```

..............................................................................................................................................................

```
    private void Page44_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ListExchanges.Count == 0)
        {
            string[] arrangeExchanges = new string[] { "Option1", "Option2", "Option3", "Option4" };
            foreach (string item4 in arrangeExchanges)
            {
                ListExchanges.Add(new ItemsModeling4 { Exchanges = item4 });
            }
        }
    }
    public static ObservableCollection<ItemsModeling4> ListExchanges { get; private set; }
```

..............................................................................................................................................................

```
public class ItemsModeling4
{
    public string Exchanges { get; set; }
}
```

..............................................................................................................................................................
Xaml

```
       <ListBox x:Name="ListBoxExchanges" Background="Transparent" 
         Tap="Selection">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Height="Auto" FontFamily="Segoe WP Semibold" FontSize="50" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,0,0,0"
                Text="{Binding Exchanges}" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

What am i doing wrong here?

It Seems like a Master - Detail binding issue. I just don't see where or how to fix it.

The system doesn't give any errors, and I've checked everything with the debugger and everything seems fine. 
The listpickers work independently and i don't see where the code might intervene and stop the one from working. It all seems good to me. 
help

Comment: Are you sure that `textBox2.Text` is returning "Domestic"? That seems like the only way that the first condition will work.

Comment: Hi John. Yes, textBox2.Text Always returns Domestic or Foreign, and the first condition is  met, and the NavigationService actually navigates to Exchanges1 ListPicker, But the listpicker will not show the chosen selection back into textbox3. Only the listpicker under the second condition will return the selection. So to sum up. Both conditions are met(when needed), but only second conditions actually returns selection.

Comment: Okay, just making sure. Could we see the code for `ListpickerExchanges2`? Or does it look the same as `ListpickerExchanges1`?

Comment: Yes it is the same as the one above. I didn't want to make the question too long and that's why i didn't add it. The only thing different, off course, are item4 becomes item5, name4 -> name5, etc

Comment: Isn't `Convert.ToString(textBox2.Text);` overkill?

Comment: @JohnOdom The code for `ListpickerExchanges2` in the `OnNavigatedTo` event is `textBox3.Text = string.Format("{0}", name5)`. Could it be that there is a confusion for the `textBox3`, and that is why the code under the last Else If condition always work, and not the one under the first If condition?

Answer (score 2):

> But if i change the code under the second Else If condition to navigate to Exchanges1 instead of Exchanges2, then the Exchanges1 listpicker displays back the selection into textbox 3, and Exchanges2 does not.

Are you sure that you are comparing culturaly correct strings? Try this compare instead for both of them.

```
if (String.Equals(a, b, InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
```

See [StringComparison Enumeration (System)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparison.aspx) and [Best Practices for Using Strings in the .NET Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465121.aspx) for more info.

---

Otherwise strings can be tricky with spaces. Try

```
String.Equals(a.Trim(), b.Trim());
```

to remove any spaces the user may be adding `\r\n` maybe?

---

Frankly since the code knows about the choices it may be better to simply provide a `ComboBox` with the selectable choices for the user instead of using a `TextBox`.

Comment: Hi OmegaMan. I wasn't completely sure so I checked, and yes I am using the same culture. I've tested it using this code under the first condition:`if (String.Equals(a, b, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))`, and this one under the second condition `if (String.Equals(c, b, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))`, and it behaves exactly as before. There is no change whatsoever.

Comment: @nunsygrey Have you tested it in the debugger? In the debugger, what does `A` and `B` look like on the first if? Check my update about spaces.

Comment: -1- The debugger fires up on both A and B. I think the problem comes from another place in my code so i will update my question with additional code for clarity.      -2- The choices come from another ListPicker, so they are already preset for the user to just those two: Domestic; Foreign(the whole page is composed of listpickers giving user the choices to choose(not type), and each dependable on the other). All of the other work the same way, but this one is different only because there are two listpickers set to display result in one single TextBox (not simultaneously off course).

Comment: @nunsygrey it might help to create a side project which mimics what you are seeing. That could help you divine the problem, but also post a sample for SO to tryout.

Comment: Yes, i use side projects always to mimic the problem. I have added additional Code and Xaml so that the problem can be replicated by SO. The only thing needed to test the code is to make a textBox2 and write inside "Domestic" or "Foreign".